# Null check on date value is not working

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am getting an error of invalid date format. I was put null check also

```
global class Lead_API_Wrapper {
global class LeadCreationRequestWrappper {

    global String EstimatedCloseDate;


}
```

Class method:

```
 global static Lead_API_Wrapper.LeadCreationResposeWrappper doPost(){
try{
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    Lead_API_Wrapper.LeadCreationRequestWrappper objRequest =  (Lead_API_Wrapper.LeadCreationRequestWrappper)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(), 

            Lead objLead = getLeadMapping(objRequest, lstUser[0].Id);

            }


@TestVisible
private static Lead getLeadMapping(Lead_API_Wrapper.LeadCreationRequestWrappper objRequest, String ownID){
    Date estimatedDate;
        if(String.isBlank(string.ValueOf(objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate)) && objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate != null){
        date dateValue = Date.parse(string.ValueOf(objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate));
         estimatedDate = Date.newInstance(dateValue.year(), dateValue.month(), dateValue.day());
            } else {
                estimatedDate = null;
         }

}
```

From portal they are sending empty date value. It is taking it as string. Please help me.

Comment: What's the value is that is assigned to wrapper variable. Which line is getting the Invalid date format error?

Answer (score 1):

This error, which I assume is the one you're getting, or very similar to it,

> Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value or request may be missing a required field

does not require a `null` check. You need instead to check `String.isBlank(incomingString)` on the value provided by your web service, which does not appear to be included in the code you shared. Attempting to convert an empty string `''` into a `Date` produces this error.

The `null` check in the code that you shared does not accomplish anything; it simply assigns `estimatedDate = objEstimatedDate` in all cases.

Comment: Hi David, whenever i am getting a value from REST service, i am storing it in a wrapper class variable as a date. Can i do that or i have to take it as a string first then put isBlank check and after convert it into date value.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual code, but if you're receiving a string, you should check whether it's blank first.

Comment: Hi @David , i was changed the code like above, still i am getting an error like Invalid Date:

Comment: Glad your problem is solved - please consider accepting the answer if it provided your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date estimatedDate;
        if(String.isNotBlank(string.ValueOf(objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate)) && String.isNotEmpty(objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate)){
        estimatedDate = Date.valueOf(string.ValueOf(objRequest.EstimatedCloseDate));
        system.debug('dateValue =============2'+estimatedDate);            
            }
```

this solved my issue. Thanks for every one for helping me.

Comment: You don't need to do `String.valueOf()` on a String variable, and you don't need to check both `String.isNotBlank()` and `String.isNotEmpty()`. `String.isNotBlank()` checks the same things as `isNotEmpty()`, plus all-whitespace.